# How to get all parameters related to a Databricks job run into python?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

I am trying to get all parameters related to a Databricks job and import them into python. These parameters should include the date, start time, duration, Status of the job(successful or failed) and all other parameters related to it.

I want to use these parameters to generate a daily report using python and the report has to contain details of all the jobs that ran either successfully or failed for everyday of the week.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Databricks Jobs REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html) for that - you can [list all jobs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsList), and for each jobs [get all runs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsList). The main problem is that you will **scrape** that API again & again.

Another possibility will be to get information about executed logs from the [diagnostic logs on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/azure-diagnostic-logs) or [audit log on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/account-settings/audit-logs.html#workspace-level-audit-log-events) - from it you can get extract information about which job run & what IDs were associated with them.  Then you can get more detailed information using the [get run API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsGet).

Or you can setup a tool called [Overwatch](https://github.com/databrickslabs/overwatch) in your workspace, and it will collect all of this information for you, plus much more information that is very useful for finding not optimal jobs, providing cost estimates, and a lot of other functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I put this here, in case someone else is looking for the same thing as I did.
In the notebook, use this code to get all job parameters:

```
args = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getCurrentBindings()
```

Found here: [How do you get the run parameters and runId within Databricks notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63018871/how-do-you-get-the-run-parameters-and-runid-within-databricks-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Databricks APIs, the [Jobs API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html) for specific, to collect all the information you need. You will need a Databricks instance URL, and authorization token to start.

Here is how your code should basically look like

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

databricks_instance = "https://adb-000000000000000.azuredatabricks.net"

jobs_url = f"{databricks_instance}/api/2.1/jobs/list"
runs_url = f"{databricks_instance}/api/2.1/jobs/runs/list?job_id="

headers = {
   'Authorization': 'Bearer ADD_YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN_HERE',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

jobs_response = requests.request("GET", jobs_url, headers=headers).json()
jobs_df = pd.DataFrame(jobs_response['jobs'])
# further logic for jobs_df

for index, row in jobs_df.iterrows():
  runs_url = runs_url + str(row['job_id'])
  runs_response = requests.request("GET", runs_url, headers=headers).json()
  runs_df = pd.DataFrame(runs_response['runs'])
  # further logic for runs_df
```

To have a complete solution, after completing the data retrieval, extraction, and filtration steps, you can save the final data frames to your DBR deltalake.

You will need to convert Pandas DF to PySpark DF and just append it to your deltalake table.

```
final_formatted_df \
  .write \
  .format("delta") \
  .outputMode("append")
```

Later on, you can connect your analytics tool (eg. PowerBI) to your deltalake table and start building dashboards.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Databricks Jobs REST API based Python code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69643674/databricks-notebook-to-read-databricks-job-statistics-and-write-it-on-a-snowflak/69728360#69728360)