# Why would post request connect but get wouldn't?

Tags: api, proxy, python-requests, databricks

Here is the code that I'm talking about:

```
import requests
http_proxy  = "http://company.cloud.databricks.com"
https_proxy = "https://company.cloud.databricks.com"
ftp_proxy   = "ftp://company.cloud.databricks.com"

proxyDict = { 
          "http"  : http_proxy, 
          "https" : https_proxy, 
          "ftp"   : ftp_proxy
            }

 headers = {
'Authorization': 'Basic YmVubnkuaG9FzczEyMzQ=',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',

}
data = '{"body" :"something"}'
response = requests.post('http://jira.company.io/rest/api/latest/issue/DO-7777', 
headers=headers, json=data, proxies=proxyDict )
```

When used on Postman this code works perfectly, but when I am using Python in Databricks (self-hosted cloud of our company) it didn't work, so I started putting this cloud databricks as the proxy parameter for the request as you can see in the code, and I started getting a 403 response code instead of a connection error, but this is only in post request. In get request I keep on getting a connection error request.

It's very weird that when I do a post request I get a 403 response code, but when I do a get request I get a connection error or `can't connect to proxy` error.

Why is that? Why is it that both don't work and why is that when using post I can connect, but get forbidden and when doing get I can't even connect what could be the possibility for this difference between get and post?

And how could I solve the problem that this request as general doesn't work on our self-hosted Databricks, but works perfectly on Postman for example? Is it indeed because it's considered a proxy?

Summary : post and get work in Postman not in Databricks where I get a connection error.  When the proxy parameter is added post works and returns a 403 response, but get is still throwing a connection error regardless of whether the proxy is supplied or not. What could be the idea behind this?

Comment: can you please check on 'Authorization'  as when we are authenticating databricks should be Bearer mode.  Sample code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69643674/databricks-notebook-to-read-databricks-job-statistics-and-write-it-on-a-snowflak/69728360#69728360

Comment: @KarthikeyanRasipalayDurairaj didnt get you. I am not trying to connect to data bricks i am trying to connect to jira from databricks by using python ot curl. I think you may misunderstood the question